# How does one transfer the contents of dynamically allocated structures and substructures of doubles to an array? (C)

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, struct, memcpy

I am working on a program whose logical flow has been greatly simplified by the liberal use of structure types.  I now need to augment the program with a function that takes all the relevant parameters, formatted as an array of doubles (as in `double *`), as one of its arguments.  My rather inexperienced self is struggling with this, unfortunately.

Currently, the structure type `parameters` is defined as

```
typedef struct parameters {

    double u1;
    double u2;
    double u3;

    model1 x[MAX_XMODELS];
    model2 y[MAX_YMODELS];
    model3 z[MAX_ZMODELS];

} parameters;
```

Types `model1`, `model2`, and `model3` are themselves structure types, *also* containing doubles and structures of doubles.  However, no matter how the tier of structures is descended, a variable of type `double` is always eventually reached.

I tried

```
parameters current;

/* Stuff that partially fills the model arrays in
   current, depending on the situation of interest */

double checkem[MAX_PARS];
memcpy(checkem,&current,sizeof(current));
```

where `MAX_PARS` is number of doubles in the struct of type `parameters`, assuming the maximum number of models used in the simulation (`MAX_XMODELS`, etc.).  And, apart from a compiler warning, this works...except there are now generally lot of junk values present in the array, because assignments to the model arrays aren't made if fewer models are used than the program is capable of handling.

Therefore, I'd *like* to redefine struct as

```
typedef struct parameters {

    double u1;
    double u2;
    double u3;

    model1 *x;
    model2 *y;
    model3 *z;

} parameters;
```

and then dynamically allocate the memory based on the number of models the program is informed to use during initialization, using something like

```
parameters current;
current.x = malloc(numx*sizeof(struct model1));
current.y = malloc(numy*sizeof(struct model2));
current.z = malloc(numz*sizeof(struct model3));
```

However, it doesn't appear that the previous `memcpy` strategy will work, since it's the pointers that are copied, not the contents that have been allocated.  So, what *will* work in my situation?  Is there no simple way to do this?

Comment: If you define "simple" as "one line of code", then no, there isn't. You'll need to manually copy over the structure members. Also note that even your first method isn't guaranteed to work because of padding and alignment requirements.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  The first method *did* actually work, as I confirmed using a `printf` loop.  Junk values plagued many of the entries, though.

Comment: If you can live with the memory overhead I would stick with the plain arrays in the structure. You may want to include a counter field in the same struct which keeps track of the number of models actually used. If you don't need a physical copy of the data I *think* (and would like to hear other's opinions) that if all elements (recursively) in `parameters` are double, a simple cast of a `parameters *` to a `double *`  should not only be safe but even be legal. After all, the memory is just a sequence of doubles, as you noticed yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the code you have will copy the pointers, not the `double`s. You need to copy the contents of each subarray, and their subarrays (`model1`, `model2`, `model3` which you don't provide the definitions of. So something like (if `model1` etc are just double[]) ...

```
parameters current;

double checkem[MAX_PARS];
double *p = &checkem[0];

// copy X into checkem
memcpy(p, &current.x, numx * sizeof(struct model1));
p += (numx * sizeof(struct model1)) / sizeof(double);

// copy Y into checkem after X
memcpy(p, &current.y, numy * sizeof(struct model2));
p += (numy * sizeof(struct model2)) / sizeof(double);

// copy Z into checkem after Y
memcpy(p, &current.z, numz * sizeof(struct model3));
```

If `model1`, `model2` and `model3` are more complex than an array of doubles, you'll need to copy the doubles separately.

Note the code is untested, but should give you a steer.

Comment: Sweet, this seems reasonable.  All `model` types are comprised of `double`s and structs that are pure `double`s -- no more pointers -- so I think this little arithmetic trick you present will still work.  Time to try it out; thanks again!

Comment: For posterity, I'd just like to add that, at least the way my compiler is configured, these three `memcpy` calls (actually four, I needed another one to nab the `double`s that preface the `model`s) were in fact sufficient to copy the parameters with perfect fidelity, despite the substructures contained within them.

Answer (score 0):

Actually a simple cast should do. I see nothing in the standard that forbids the cast here. Specifically, the alignment needed for the target type is matched (it's a double, too) and memory layout like padding which would prevent the elements from being contiguous in memory shouldn't be an issue with doubles. I wouldn't memcopy large data around unless it's necessary.

Last not least it's extremely simple and extremely hard to get wrong.

```
void f(double *argArray);

typedef struct parameters {

    double u1;
    double u2;
    double u3;

    model1 x[MAX_XMODELS];
    model2 y[MAX_YMODELS];
    model3 z[MAX_ZMODELS];

} parameters;

parameters pObj;

void g()
{
   f((double *)&pObj);
}
```